# Extra arguement in method call

Tags: ios, swift

I'm looking to call a method from my ViewController class that is declared in another class.

in my Animator class:

```
class Animator {

    func animate(view:View!, scrollView:UIScrollView!) {
    //animation code
    }
}
```

but when i call the method in my View Controller class

```
Animator.animate(viewA, scrollView:scrollView)
```

i get a **`"Extra Argument 'scrollView' in call`** error

It's so simple and i'm so confused on why this error is showing for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `animate` as if it were a class method. If you want it to be a class method, you need to do:

```
class func animate(view:View!, scrollView:UIScrollView!)
```

If you want it to be an instance method, first create an instance of `Animator`, then call `animate` on the instance:

```
a = Animator()
a.animate(view, scrollView:scrollView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Should that be `UIView` instead of `View`?

```
func animate(view:UIView!, scrollView:UIScrollView!) { ... }
```

And you are calling this on a class, so it needs to be a class method.

```
class func animate(view:UIView!, scrollView:UIScrollView!) { ... }
```

And I also believe that call needs to have a named argument:

```
Animator.animate(view: viewA, scrollView:scrollView)
```

Error messages in Swift can be misleading :(